# Как вытащить все пункты из popup_menu в активном окне (sublime api)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text-3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытащить через sublime api все, что находится в окне автокомплита?

У меня получилось вытащить только те операторы, которые есть в открытых документах и прописаны в самих документах используя

```
sublime.active_window().views()
```

Но меня интересует как получить весь попап список.

p.s Sublime Text 3

P.s.s Буду очень благодарен если предоставите название литературы с примерами по питону для углубленной работы с системой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные для автокомплита складываются из [нескольких источников](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/completions.html): сниппеты, захардкоженные дополнения, файлы .sublime-completions, слова текущего текста. За исключением сниппетов данные для view можно получить функцией `view.extract_completions(prefix)` (можно также обратить внимание на плагин [SublimeAllAutocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete)). Для получения сниппетов Sublime не предоставляет API.

Для получения сниппетов можно воспользоваться плагином [**SnippetCaller**](https://github.com/shagabutdinov/sublime-snippet-caller) (при установке через Package Control требуются зависимости в виде плагинов Context, QuickSearchEnhanced, LocalVariable, Extension, Statement).

Используя этот плагин сниппеты можно извлечь методом `snippet_caller.get_snippets(view, False)`. Возвращается список словарей следующего вида:  `{'name': '__magic__', 'path': 'Packages/Python/Snippets/__magic__.sublime-snippet', 'content': '__${1:init}__', '_scope': 'source.python', '_trigger': '__', 'description': '__magic__', 'tabTrigger': '__'}`

Таким образом, можно получить отдельно все слова из completions и отдельно сниппеты:

```
import string
from SnippetCaller import snippet_caller

found_snippets = snippet_caller.get_snippets(view, False)
completions = [view.extract_completions(x) for x in string.ascii_letters]
```

Можно наверно слепить слова и сниппеты в один список, но не вижу в этом смысла.